# PHP - Array to string conversion in D:\xammp\htdocs\ch4-image-gallery\views\upload.php on line 19

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple Upload Image function. For that I have these 2 snippets.

1. Form to upload new images.

   ```
   <?php
     // Form to upload images
     return "<h1>Upload New Images</h1>
     <form method='post' action='index.php?page=upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
         <lebel>Find an image to upload</lebel>
         <input type='file' name='image-data' accept='image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif'>
         <input type='submit' name='new-image' value='Upload'>
     </form>";
   ?>
   ```
2. PHP file to control upload mechanism and basically to show image data:

   ```
   <?php
   // code for uploading images
   $fileIsUploaded = isset($_POST['new-image']);    // check if file is uploaded via upload-form
   if($fileIsUploaded)
       upload();    // calling function 'upload'
   else
       $output = include_once "views/upload-form.php";     // if not, then run to default
   return $output;

   //new function to control upload mechanism
   function upload(){
       $out = "<pre>";
       $out .=print_r($_FILES, true);
       $out .= "</pre>";
       return $out;
   }
   ?>
   ```

   If I run this , I'm supposed to get something like bellow:

   ```
    Array (
    [image-data] => Array (
    [name] => alberte-lea.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpYPcBjK
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 119090
    )
    )
   ```

   But I'm getting following error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xammp\htdocs\ch4-image-gallery\views\upload.php on line 19
>
> print_r(Array, true)

Any help, please? I'm quite new in PHP.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not passed file data to function

```
upload($_FILES);
```

And accept it in function and print that

```
function upload($data){
 $out = "<pre>";
 $out .=print_r($data, true);
 $out .= "</pre>";
 return $out;
}
```

Comment: What the reason to pass global variables as an argument?

Comment: This answer cannot be valid, there's no sense in this change.

Answer (score 0):

Its conversion Error because you're using [`print_r(Array, true)`](https://www.copahost.com/blog/php-array-to-string/) which is used when you are converting an array to string.

PS: First you have to configure PHP to upload file/s `file_uploads = On`.

So, in your above code you're not passing the array to your `print_r` method use this one:

```
<?php
  // code for uploading images
  $fileIsUploaded = isset($_POST['new-image']);    // check if file is uploaded via upload-form
  if($fileIsUploaded)
      upload($_FILES);    // calling function 'upload'
  else
      $output = include_once "views/upload-form.php";     // if not, then run to default
  return $output;

  //new function to control upload mechanism
  function upload($your_files){
      $out = "<pre>";
      $out .=print_r($your_files, true);
      $out .= "</pre>";
      return $out;
  }
?>
```

1) https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

2) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-_files-array-http-file-upload-variables/

3) https://www.copahost.com/blog/php-array-to-string/